# Models not being saved in Play Framework

Tags: java, model, playframework, updatemodel

Assume a model named `User`:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(
        Long.class, User.class
    );
}
```

When I attempt to update an instance of `User` in my controller:

```
    User user = User.find.where().eq("username", username).findUnique();

    if(user != null) {
        user.username = "some_new_username";
        user.save();
    }
```

no changes seem to be committed. I read somewhere that when you alter a model instance by its property, it does not get dirty and therefore no changes take place. Hence you should use a setter instead. In the documentation of Play Framework it is said that those setters (and getters) are generated automatically, but using `user.setUsername(username)` gives me a compilation error:

```
cannot find symbol [symbol: method setUsername(java.lang.String)] [location: class models.User]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding custom setters?

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    public String username;

    public void setUsername(String _username) {
        username = _username;
    }

    @Constraints.Required
    public String password;

    public void setPassword(String _password) {
        password = _password;
    }

    public static Finder<Long, User> find = new Finder<Long, User>(
        Long.class, User.class
    );
}
```

Comment: This indeed does get the job done, although I'm quite disappointed the automatically generated setter did not. Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem, well of course it will work if I add the setters and getters by hand. Why doesn't Play Framework generate the setters and getters while in the documentation it says it does?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, automatic getter/setter translation is broken in Play2. Your assignment:

```
user.username = "some_new_username";
```

should have triggered the function call:

```
user.setUsername("some_new_username");
```

This translation seems to be broken in Play 2. Here's [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16650841/getter-setter-translation-in-play-framework-2) on the subject.